# Azure Virtual Network Manager peering

Tags: azure-networking, peering

Am I correct in thinking, that creating a peering via AVNM can only do gateways that are VPN/Express Route?

I want on my peering the box that says "use `target`'s remote gateway for route server"

As so - but the docs suggest I can only use a gateway that's a VPN/Express Route

[image]